# Compile the latest Boost on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ppa, gcc, g++, boost

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I need `libboost-all-dev` at least 1.56 to compile a library. The default `libboost-all-dev` on my Ubuntu is `libboost1.54-all-dev`.

I tried to find a suitable PPA, but didn't find one.

Are there any PPAs with `libboost1.56-all-dev` or `libboost1.58-all-dev` or better? Like `libboost1.62-all-dev` for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty?

Comment: Couldn't you use the version from 14.10 or 15.04, for example, and force-install it?

Comment: my crappy Ubuntu Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 won't upgrade, it's just 14.04, hm

Comment: I'm not suggesting you upgrade your system. I'm suggesting that  you download the amd64 `libboost-all-dev` package for 16.04, for example, from [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libboost-all-dev/download) and see if you can force-install it on your 14.04 system

Comment: ok i download .deb file instead of using apt-get